# Flask Get the url variables in a before request?

Tags: python, flask

In Flask I have url rules with variables. For example:

```
my_blueprint.add_url_rule('/<user_token>/bills/',view_func=BillsView.as_view('bills'))
```

This is going to pass the `user_token` variable to the `BillsView`'s `get` and `post` methods. 
I am trying to intercept that `user_token` variable in the `before_request` of my blueprint.

Here is my blueprint `before_request`:

```
def before_req():
  ...
  ...

my_blueprint.before_request(before_req)
```

The closest I have come is to use `request.url_rule`. But that does not give me the content of the variable. Just the rule that matches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Register a URL processor using [`@app.url_value_preprocessor`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.url_value_preprocessor), which takes the endpoint and values matched from the URL. The values dict can be modified, such as popping a value that won't be used as a view function argument, and instead storing it in the `g` namespace.

```
from flask import g

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def store_user_token(endpoint, values):
    g.user_token = values.pop('user_token', None)
```

The docs include a [detailed example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/patterns/urlprocessors/) of using this for extracting an internationalization language code from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [URL preprocessors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/) as described above, another approach to get args passed to the URL explicitly will be to use this.

```
@app.before_request
def get_request_args():
    "Provides all request args"
    request_args = {**request.view_args, **request.args} if request.view_args else {**request.args}
    print('All Request args ',request_args)
```

More info in the documentation of [request.args](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args) and [request.view_args](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Request.view_args)